# Ignore an log4net Error in powershell

Tags: powershell, log4net

I have an issue on the script, basically I don't use any log4net or whatever and im not planning, but some resource which i access during my script i suppose has some references to this log4net, so i get this messages:

> log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section
>   'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file
>   for the  and  elements. The configuration
>   section should look like:

I don't really care about this, as this is also not a real error, i would prefere to somehow hide this messages from the propmpt window, is this possible?

How can I ignore this information, without too much hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message comes from the [log4net internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html), and means that not log4net configuration information is found in the config file. What I find strange is that this kind of info is usually opt-in:

> There are 2 different ways to enable internal debugging in log4net.
>   These are listed below. The preferred method is to specify the
>   `log4net.Internal.Debug` option in the application's config file.
>
> - Internal debugging can also be enabled by setting a value in the application's configuration file (not the log4net configuration file,
>     unless the log4net config data is embedded in the application's config
>     file). The log4net.Internal.Debug application setting must be set to
>     the value true. For example:
>
>   This setting is read immediately on startup an will cause all internal debugging messages to be emitted.
> - To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging property to true.
>     Obviously the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced.

So either the code of one component uses the code approach, or there is a configuration value set to true. Your options are:

- look through the configuration files for a reference to the log4net.Internal.Debug config key; if you find one set to true, set it to false.
- add an empty log4net section in the configuration file to satisfy the configurator and prevent it from complaining
- if the internal debugging is set through code, you may be able to redirect console out and the trace appenders (see link for where the internal debugging writes to) but this really depends on your environment so you'll need to dig a bit more to find how to catch all outputs. Not really simple

Comment: Your are correct, i think it is the best way to add an empty section to config file, but how to do that?

Comment: add a section for it, <section name="log4net" 
     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/> then an empty log4net tag <log4net />

Comment: can i somehow load it seperatly in the script, because i'm not sure which config file to modify, i tried to add this to my main config file, but no success

Comment: It really depends on what components you are using in your script (executables or assemblies, loaded by you or another way?). Try looking for the different config files that may be used you may find some info in one of them